# Avoid re-render with `useCallback`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out why when I click on a specific component its sibling it will render too

```
function CountButton({increment, count, number}) {
  console.log(`Render CountButton ${number}`)

  return <button onClick={() => increment(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
}

function DualCounter() {
  const [count1, setCount1] = React.useState(0)
  const increment1 = React.useCallback(() => setCount1(c => c + 1), [])
  const [count2, setCount2] = React.useState(0)
  const increment2 = React.useCallback(() => setCount2(c => c + 1), [])
  console.log('Render DualCounter')

  return (
    <>
      <CountButton count={count1} increment={increment1} number={1} />
      <CountButton count={count2} increment={increment2} number={2} />
    </>
  )
}
```

I use `useCallback` and I pass theses function to use avoid that in any render the functions reference will be a different reference.

Comment: Because you pass in count1 / count2 as a prop as well. This props is changed so the component is re-rendered

Comment: If DualCounter is re-renders, it's children will render too.. You can use memo

Answer (score 5):

You are seeing a re-render on the sibling `<CountButton />` component, because each time you hit the button to update the counter, you are actually updating a state value in the parent component `<DualCounter />`, which causes a re-render on that component as well.

And since `DualCounter` is re-rendered, child components will re-render as well, which in this case includes both `<CountButton />` elements.

A solution to prevent this, would be wrapping CountButton component with [React.memo()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). This will prevent a re-render on a component that didn't have any change on the props values.

Example below:

```js
function CountButton({increment, count, number}) {
  console.log(`Render CountButton ${number}`)

  return <button onClick={() => increment(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
}

const CountButtonMemo = React.memo(CountButton)

function DualCounter() {
  const [count1, setCount1] = React.useState(0)
  const increment1 = React.useCallback(() => setCount1(c => c + 1), [])
  const [count2, setCount2] = React.useState(0)
  const increment2 = React.useCallback(() => setCount2(c => c + 1), [])
  console.log('Render DualCounter')

  return (
    <>
      <CountButtonMemo count={count1} increment={increment1} number={1} />
      <CountButtonMemo count={count2} increment={increment2} number={2} />
    </>
  )
```

Another solution would be not updating the `DualCounter` state on each change caused by events on your `CountButton` components, which will stop triggering unwanted re-renders on their siblings. You could handle the state directly on each CountButton component if this made sense for your app.

Alternatively, you could use a React state management tool, such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), which also solves exactly this issue, by taking charge of delegating the state of your app separated from your components themselves.

Comment: Using Redux opens up a whole other can of worms though :) There are more modern alternatives to it!

Comment: I thought that if the user clicks on the first counter, it updates the `count1`, which re-render the `DualComponent` but because the properties are the same for the second `CountButtonMemo` it shouldn't be re-render. I though a component will render if its props changes or  updating state inside the component

Comment: Yes, "a component will render if its props changes or updating state inside the component" is correct, but also a child re-render will be triggered if the parent component re-renders too, no matter the reason. To prevent the actual child component re-render from happening, when there are no changes in the props, using a memoization technique such as React.memo() can help.

Comment: OK, Now, It's clear but I thought the reconciliation algorithm avoid this re-render if the props doesn't change

Comment: It's understandable to arrive to that conclusion, however the reconciliation algorithm just takes care of detecting the changes in the data across the components (props, state), then triggering a re-render on the component where it changed, and then traversing the tree down further, until no more components are left ot be updated (rerendered). So in short, by default the rerender happens when the component state updated, the parent component state is updated, or when the component props change. In this case, the reason is because the parent DualCounter has been updated.